# Drawing diagrams in Pages don't stay in place with text

Tags: macos, pages

I feel like I'm missing something, but maybe this is just a flaw in the software.

Whenever I draw diagrams in Pages, or insert images, they seem to just float there, and if I change text above, it causes the text to go past the image I inserted. For example, if I have a paragraph of text that references "the diagram below", and I add another paragraph above it, the diagram would now be above the paragraph of text because it doesn't move with the text as its editing.

Comment: Which version of pages are you using?

Comment: 5.1. Apparently there's an App Store update, which I'll do now, but I doubt that'll make a difference

Comment: Updated, and the problem is actually worse - inserting something pushes headers, text etc. out of the way which isn't what I want

Comment: Is there such thing as place holder?

Comment: Had a look and there doesn't seem to be, nope

Comment: What do you get when you change the **Text Wrap** settings for the object?  These are found in the inspector under the **Arrange** tab. (Your OP does not mention any attempt to change these settings.)

Answer (score 1):

Pages allows for several ways to insert graphics and either float them or anchor with the text.

### Dragging in a image or object

**Press Command <kbd>⌘</kbd> as you drag and the blinking cursor will indicate the insertion point**

This will keep the picture relative to the text where it was inserted.

#### Working with the Inspector

The settings for objects are found in the **Inspector**.

Stay on Page

This will anchor the image or object relative to the *page* regardless of the text added.

Move with Text

This will allow the image to move with the *text* as more is added.  Essentially anchoring the image to a place in the text so that when text is added above the insertion point, the image will move down the page along with the text.

---

[image: Object Placement]

Comment: The "move with text" is bugged as hell, even in the 6.3.1.

Comment: Yep, buggy.  Hopefully improvements are on the way.